# Fabric, cluster, server

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, processor

Here is the marketing page for the Intel True Scale Fabric

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/infiniband/truescale-infiniband.html

> The Intel® True Scale Fabric Host Channel Adapters (HCA) along with
>   its host stack, Performance Scaled Messaging (PSM), were specifically
>   developed to provide an optimized, connectionless transport mechanism
>   for each server. Together with the Intel® True Scale Fabric Switch
>   12000 Series, a very high-performing fabric for HPC clusters and their
>   Message Passing Interface (MPI) applications is created. Every member
>   of the Intel True Scale Fabric Switch 12000 Series provides
>   predictable, scalable performance, even under heavy traffic and
>   extreme message rate load. All Intel True Scale Fabric products can be
>   managed via the Intel True Scale Fabric Suite, providing an overall
>   view into the health, status, and performance of a truly high
>   performance computer cluster.

From there, i understand that a Fabric is the set of Host adapters, switches, interconnect and software tools to make a cluster.

I am not sure then how much fabric, cluster and servers are synonyms for the same thing? What are differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good explanation is [here](https://code.facebook.com/posts/360346274145943/introducing-data-center-fabric-the-next-generation-facebook-data-center-network/).

Basically a **cluster is made of servers, each one interconnected in a hierarchical topology**. I'm not an expert on this field but basically you have server racks (i.e. computers) connected together with TOR (Top Of Rack) switch, each TOR switch is connected together with a cluster switch. 
If needed more cluster can be connected together, again with an hierarchical topology .

A **fabric is and alternative to aggregation of clusters and it is made of servers, each one interconnected with a uniform HPC topology**. The base unit is a server pod, composed of server racks and fabric switches. Fabric switches are connected to spine switches that are connected by edge switches.

As I understand it, fabrics are a replacement of clusters of clusters.

I don't know what Intel brand names like *Intel® True Scale Fabric Host Channel Adapters* and *Intel® True Scale Fabric Switch 12000* designates in term of hardware but my guess is that the HCA is an adapter used to connect a server rack with the Fabric Switch 12000 (that can be connected together through spine switched that can be connected... you got it) though a protocol like [InfiniBand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InfiniBand).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ethernet shared bus. Limitation is that in the shared bus, collisions means loss of the frame. The CSMA/CD checks whether frame can be sent before sending. Nevertheless, performance is hindered.

Enter switches, to reduce the number of devices communicating over a given communication segment. Full-duplex.

Then switches investigated the ability to connect any device to any device. Again, collision occurs.

The crossbar switch, in silicon form, enables this any to any connection. It is possible to simulteaneously send frames over several segments, no collision !

more here http://etherealmind.com/what-is-the-definition-of-switch-fabric/